# Chrome CSS3 Box shadow text field issue

Tags: google-chrome, css

Has anyone run into an issue in Google Chrome when applying a box shadow to a text input? I have this obscure issue where once in a while when typing in the input, the box shadow appears to double. I've tried several things but nothing seems to fix it. Worst of all, the issue is very inconsistent.  The only thing that I can do to semi-consistently have this issue appear is reset the browser cache every time.

[image]

The CSS being applied to the input is as follows:

```
input[type=text] {
  padding: 7px 0 7px 10px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -o-border-radius: 2px;
  -ms-border-radius: 2px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-box-shadow: #e4e4e4 4px 5px 10px inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: #e4e4e4 4px 5px 10px inset;
  -o-box-shadow: #e4e4e4 4px 5px 10px inset;
  box-shadow: #e4e4e4 4px 5px 10px inset;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  outline: none;   
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle of the code in action. http://jsfiddle.net/S5xzM/

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

[Edit] The version of Chrome this is currently happening in is 14.0.835

Comment: for me works the same as firefox in 14.0.835

Comment: It does happen to me, Chrome Mac 14.0.835.202. Only the first time I write stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Interesting problem!

This is most definitely a Webkit bug. This only happens if you put `outline: none;` on the focus pseudo-selector.

This is the only workaround I could find:

```
input[type=text]:focus {
    outline-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    outline-offset: 10px;
}
```

I tried various methods, such as `outline-width: 0`, or `outline-color: transparent`, but they didn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gvh2L/